# How to create different uiactionsheet for two buttons ?

Tags: iphone

Hi here i developing small application. In a subclass screen i have two buttons. When i press the first button, it will shows four actionsheet. When i press second button it wil shows five actionsheet. I was successfully shows it. But i cant set second button actions of five actionsheet. In my code the when i press second button of first actionsheet, it wil actioned first button of first actionsheet. Here i want set actions for individual actionsheets. Pls help me. Here is my code is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ( indexPath.row == 0)
{
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Edit" otherButtonTitles:@"Remove", @"Sell",@"Scrap", nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];
}
if ( indexPath.row == 1 ) 
{
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Unsell" otherButtonTitles:@"Edit Item", @"Edit Sale",@"Sold",@"Scrap", nil];
    popupQuery.tag=5;
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];
}
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0) 
{
    Updateasset *object=[[Updateasset alloc]initWithNibName:@"Updateasset" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:object animated:NO];
    [object release];
} 
else if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Remove" message:@"Do you want to Remove"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} 
else if (buttonIndex == 2)
{
    Egarageselling *object=[[Egarageselling alloc]initWithNibName:@"Egarageselling" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:object animated:YES];
    [object release];
} 
else if (buttonIndex == 3) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Scrap" message:@"Do you want to Scrap"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 4) 
{

}
else if (buttonIndex == 5) 
{

}
else if (buttonIndex == 6) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Scrap" message:@"Do you want to Scrap"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 7) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Scrap" message:@"Do you want to Scrap"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 8) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Scrap" message:@"Do you want to Scrap"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 9) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Scrap" message:@"Do you want to Scrap"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
}
```

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set different tags for two actionsheets like
popupQuery.tag=5;
popupQuery.tag=6;

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if(actionSheet.tag==5)
    {
       if (buttonIndex == 0) 
       {
       }
      so on
    }
    if(actionSheet.tag==6)
    {
       if (buttonIndex == 0) 
       {
       }
       so on
    }

 }
```

Comment: it wil work but it also actioned with first buttons of actionsheets how to solve

Comment: this is my  code.
if ( indexPath.row == 0)
 {
  ...
  popupQuery.tag=5;
  .....
 }
 if ( indexPath.row == 1 ) 
 {
  ....
  popupQuery1.tag=6;
  ...
 }

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 
 if (actionSheet.tag=5) 
 {
  if (buttonIndex == 0) 
  {
  }
 }
 
 if (actionSheet.tag=6)
 {
  if (buttonIndex == 0) 
  {
   
  } 
  so on
}

Answer (score 0):

I might just add, that in a situation like this I would say that best practice is to make your actionsheet to public or private instance variables. It would look like this in your header file (for public):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *as1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *as2;
```

In your implementation file you synthesize them, like this:

```
@synthesize as1, as2;
```

Then remember to set them from where you now allocate your popupQuery's today:

```
...
self.as1 = popupQuery;
...

...
self.as2 = popupQuery;
...
```

And in your delegate method you can now do it like this (which I also find more readable if I should ever present the code for another developer):

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if(self.as1 == actionSheet) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) { ... }
        ...
    }

    if(self.as2 == actionSheet) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

I hope you find it useful in this and many other cases. I myself, do it like that, all the time. No harm in having a public or private reference for that matter to you objects. You never know when they might come in handy.